# Client wants a re-order form for their business. Best approach?

Tags: forms

A client wants a customer re-order form for their Web site, but it's getting pretty lengthy. Here is what the page looks like:
http://fjt.dnsalias.net/interoofficesolutions/index.php?option=com_chronocontact&chronoformname=SmileStarters

There has to be an easier way to do this. Any suggestions?

Lallo

Comment: It looks like the link is not working.

Answer (score 1):

1. Store successful customer orders in their account.
2. Create an 'order history' page based on the stored info.
3. Allow them to log in and click the 'reorder' button next to previous orders.
4. Upon reorder, add those same items to the cart and send them to the final 'confirm' checkout stage.

(The link to your form is dead, but the above process is what I recommend; it removes the need for complex forms altogether.)

Answer (score 0):

Try offering "packages" that are the pre assembled SKUs in some logical quantity.  "Starter Pack" "Stocking Up Pack" "Bare Essentials Pack" or something like that.

Offer a customize button off of those packages are loads your form (or something similar) and pre fills the quantity fields that your customer can tweak.

For just the order form, use a tabbed interface for main groups so the page isn't so tall.  Maybe each of your H1's is a tab heading